# Text to Speech in OS X Application

Tags: macos, sdk, text-to-speech

I am creating a native OS X application, and I was surprised at how difficult it is to find documentation on text-to-speech with native APIs. What would be the easiest way of having my application speak (using Alex's voice for example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call “text-to-speech” is also commonly abbreviated as TTS and alternatively called “speech synthesis”.

The Cocoa class [NSSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the API to use. The canonical sample code is [CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample).

There also is a guide to “[Speech Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Speech/Speech.html)” and a “[Speech Synthesis Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)” available.

Finally, there are [lower level APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Speech_Synthesis_Manager/Reference/reference.html) available if you need access to stuff that is abstracted away for you by NSSpeechSynthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this please [NSSpeechRecognizer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104484/nsspeechrecognizer-example)

its a text to speech built in library for OS X .. `NSSpeechRecognizer`