# final version of my request:how to convert speech to text

Tags: objective-c++

I asked about converting speech to text in c++ but my question seemed to be unclear and also the answer I got. I have already heard that we should have "speech" in a wave file. so what to do after that? I said  I want to do it on my own, I mean without using windows's facilities and API.c++ libraries are allowed if there are. I need to know how it works, is it impossible?? that it will take a million years. there is no tutorial thing in Google about it. at least tell me some steps to light my path.what are the titles of things I have to do or learn? there are so many thing that are using converting speech to text, like i can say john to my mobile phone and it calls john. does not it recognize john? it seems to be a little bit easy so it is possible to learn not 'a million years'. I need to learn how to convert just some short  sentences to string. for now the qualities like pronunciation is not important . what are the bases and where I can learn about them? look , i need to say one sentence to computer and then computer has to choose one the answers that I have already recorded, so I need to convert to string to compare that string with the recorded string sentences. please some one tell me what to do or what to search or where to look or where to go or who to see?

Comment: If you want to do this on the mac, then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845791/text-to-speech-in-os-x-application).

Comment: Can you be bothered to google, if you are so willing to learn? http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/ is one of the first things that appears. But overall this is complicated, and frankly speaking you seem to not really have a grasp of the complexity of issues involved.

Comment: thank you my friend for your comment. yes you are right I don't have enough grasp about what I want. but you seem to not read my question completely. I am not going to write a recognition engine and it does not need to be clever like 'ILA Voice Assistant' in the system that I want, there is only a limited number of speeches which I know them right now     and a limited number of answers than I now what they are. I need to find a way to make a speech have a token or sign to use that to gain its answer.

Comment: look  every speech (sentence) has a frequency that its shape differs just a little in the shape of frequency if another person say the same sentence. so the frequency might be a flag. that I can write my program that if features of a frequency is like "this", ("this" can be some numbers that are the features of a speech frequency) then choose one of the strings that I put before.

Comment: at first I thought that converting a speech to text is a little bit easy. but now let's twist complexities. imagine that you don't know English but answer some questions that you recognize what they are  just from some signs and your answer is just a movement of your body. ----so for my sound file what the those signs would be to use them and reach its answer????????

Comment: my last comment : suppose that  you record your voice , you say "how are you and record it and your brother says "how are you" and record it and then a friend of yours do the same. now we have three sound file with the same content with a little difference in quality of these three voice. now these three sound files must have a special sign the same sign for every of three files. then I can use than sign to figure out what the answer is.

Comment: suppose that you have strings "good night" , "good morning" , "good bye". then you say "good night" with your voice and record it. so the answer must be string "good night", now forget about converting speech to text. what exclusive feature a sound file including "good night" has that the other sound files don't? I mean something like frequency. then I can write IF ' that special thing ' is like some thing for example ("!@RE&*")  then the answer is "some string"

Comment: Am I dreaming about something impossible??

Comment: take things easy guys it seems to be very easy but I don't know

Comment: I am running out of English I can not find new words to describe what my question is

Comment: I am looking for something like the one old cellphones (the ancient cellphones) had named 'auto call ' I think. which you say john and it calls john. how it finds out john or other names and calls?